# xlsx xml parser support of special charaters

Tags: xml, special-characters, code-injection, xlsx

the Xlsx seems not to support the [standard of xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) , which requires the xml to "understand" the 5 `<>'"&` as `&name;` and have very strange behavior.

anyone knows what to inject to `sharedStrings.xml` when use of `<>'"&` inorder for it not to break the file?

Edit : as it seems the 
' can be replaced with ' 
& can be replaced with &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlsx format does not support all the special characters, as there xml does not expect to handle ascii format. the solution is to use unicode format.

if you do have a problem then you cant convert to ascii format all the charachters, and you have to change not one of the special 5 like insert space instead.

im not sure that excel developers tested xml files that are declared in the first tag not beening UTF-8